# Omit query parameter from url if its null using openapi spec

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

I have generated client code for my service using openapi spec. In one of the endpoints its taking few optional query parameters. The problem is even if a query param is null its including that param in url with empty value. I want it to be omitted from url if its null.

The query parameter is already optional in openapi spec

Query param definition in openapi spec

```
name: "modifiedSince"
schema:
  type: integer
  format: int64
required: false
```

Example:

modifiedSince and modifiedBefore are two optional parameters

generated url if both params are null: /xxxxx/xxxxxx?modifiedSince&modifiedBefore

expected url if both params are null: /xxxxx/xxxxxx